# MySQL - Can I check if two columns exist in a sub query together?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

pretty much take this sample query for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE field1 AND field2 IN
    (
        SELECT field1, field2
        FROM some_table
        WHERE COUNT(field1) > 5
    ) AS subquery
)
```

I want field1 and field2 returned in my final result set, as the field1 and field2 returned in the result set from this inner query

```
            SELECT field1, field2
            FROM some_table
            WHERE COUNT(field1) > 5
```

What is the right syntax here? Certainly the first query would work if I only had `where field1 IN subquery`. Does `field1 AND field2` even make sense here? As, I want the field1 value where field1 >5, therefore, the field2 value in that same row will already be returned?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: The query you are presenting is malformed. Columns not present in the `GROUP BY` clause must show up aggregated in the `SELECT` list. Please fix the query.

Comment: I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE (field1, field2) IN
    (
        SELECT field1, field2
        FROM some_table
        WHERE <conditions>
    ) AS subquery
)
```

Comment: Though the question is not correct, this solution should work for a well formed query.

Comment: This is the solution I'm looking for. Like, how to format the WHERE condition using two columns. Thanks!